# A town is to a county as a place is to a what?

Tags: analogy, generic-term

I'm trying to find a generic term for the container of a place.  E.G. a county contains a town or a country contains a state.  So, what contains a place?

**EDIT:**
To add context to the question, I'm developing an application that has the need to display information about towns, counties, provinces, territories, etc. One of the pieces of information required is a reference to the "place" that most immediately contains said place. This application will be used internationally and so a generic term was desired.

Comment: Terms for geographical units and their relationships to one another are highly localized. In much of the U.S., a town can exist in multiple counties, and in the U.K., the state is constituted by several countries. We need a great deal more context to be able to answer correctly; for example, how do you plan to use this term, and how do you define *place*? After all, a country can be a place, as can a county or a town; it is no more specific than *region* or *area* or *location*.

Comment: @choster, you are very right that geographical units and their relationships to one another are highly localized.  To add context to the question, I'm developing an application that has the need to display information about towns, counties, provinces, territories, etc.  One of the pieces of information required is a reference to the "place" that most immediately contains said place.  This application will be used internationally and so a generic term was desired.  Region, area, or location are all potential answers to my question.

Comment: I think *region* is the word you may be looking for.

Comment: If the "place" is an administrative division of level n, I don't think that there is a widely used word (or expression) to refer to the administrative division of level n-1, that will be the same for all n (i.e. Country, State, town, district, ...). "Parent_division" may fit for source code and software documentation,  but not for HMI. I rather suggest that you use a function getting the word corresponding to the parent division from the word corresponding to place type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a difficult question because "place" has no definable boundary, whereas a town or a county does.

With that caveat in mind, I'll offer "area," "region," "neighborhood," or even "environs" as words that can contain "place."  One's choice is a matter of scale and context, of course.

"Town" or "county" could also contain "place," for that matter :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say an environment contains a place, as long as place is defined (as a town or a region, for example): the North Sea environment contains many small islands.  The problem is how one should think of a 'container': is this an idea? Is the container something I can draw on a map?  Is the container bounded in some way?

Answer (score 0):

For the use intended I'd choose [***location***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/location).

> A particular place or position:
>   *'the property is set in a convenient location'*

I like location better than [surrounding](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/surrounding) but it's a matter of taste.

> All round a particular place or thing:
>   *'Cardiff and the surrounding area'*

References:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/location
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/surrounding